# Why does hydrogen fuse in a star?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, stars, fusion, stellar-physics

I have only had basic classroom experience with physics but I have done a lot of research on my own and I am wondering why a newly formed star or any planetary body composed purely of hydrogen will adopt any state of matter besides its gaseous state.

I understand that as you get closer to the core 'gravity increases" but wouldn't the pull from the surrounding atoms negate any effects strong enough to cause a change in state?

Comment: "as you get closer to the core gravity increases" not true, gravity decreases although pressure increases which becomes more important

Comment: As pressure increases, temperature increases, to the point where the hydrogen becomes a plasma rather than a gas.

Comment: " wouldn't the pull from the surrounding atoms negate" if you mean the surrounding atoms cancel out their gravitational pull one another , you might want to look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity) to see that the net gravitational force on atoms in the star is inward and not zero.

Comment: read the answer of tfb here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402192/star-formation-how-did-gravity-forced-nuclear-fusion/402194#402194